# How to do some complex calculation between columns in spark Dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

For example:

```
val calresult1 = indexedresult.withColumn("_4", lit(1))
calresult1.show()
+---+---+------------------+---+
| _1| _2|                _3| _4|
+---+---+------------------+---+
|  5|  2|               5.0|  1|
|  5|  0|0.5555555555555554|  1|
|  4|  0| 3.222222222222222|  1|
|  3|  5|               1.0|  1|
......
```

I can do some simple calculation using +,-,*,/:

```
val calresult2 = calresult1.withColumn("_5", calresult1.col("_4")/(calresult1.col("_3"))).select("_1","_2","_5")
calresult2.show()
+---+---+------------------+
| _1| _2|                _5|
+---+---+------------------+
|  5|  2|               0.2|
|  5|  0|1.8000000000000007|
|  4|  0|               1.0|
......
```

but can't use pow and sqrt:

```
    val calresult2 = calresult1.withColumn("_5", pow(calresult1.col("_4")+(calresult1.col("_3")))).select("_1","_2","_5")
calresult2.show()
```

Error:

```
Error:(414, 53) could not find implicit value for parameter impl: breeze.numerics.pow.Impl[org.apache.spark.sql.Column,VR]
val calresult2 = calresult1.withColumn("_5", pow(calresult1.col("_4")+(calresult1.col("_3")))).select("_1","_2","_5")
                                                ^
```

How to implement complex fomula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pow()` takes 2 arguments of type Double.  I believe you're missing the 2nd argument:

```
pow(calresult1.col("_4")+(calresult1.col("_3")))
```

Providing the 2nd argument as in the following example should fix the problem:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val calresult2 = calresult1.withColumn(
  "_5", pow(calresult1.col("_4")+(calresult1.col("_3")), 2.0)
).select(
  "_1","_2","_5"
).show

+---+---+------------------+
| _1| _2|                _5|
+---+---+------------------+
|  5|  2|              36.0|
|  5|  0|2.4197530864197523|
|  4|  0|17.827160493827154|
|  3|  5|               4.0|
+---+---+------------------+
```

Comment: How to control the precision? eg: transform 2.4197530864197523 to 2.41975.

Comment: Just use `round()` with precision as 2nd argument.  Using the previous example, `round(pow(calresult1.col("_4")+(calresult1.col("_3")), 2.0), 5)` would give the wanted precision.

Answer (score 0):

Just use built-in functions:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{pow, sqrt}
```

and you'll be good.

In general you can use `UserDefinedFunctions` but there are not required here.